# Cant start with custom docker image on Macos

Tags: docker, nginx

So I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

I build it using:
`docker build .`

I get the ID: `0154623d6179`

And then I run:

`docker run 0154623d6179 -d -p 80:80`

and I get the error:
`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-d\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order in the params matters:

```
docker -d -p 80:80 run 0154623d6179
```

Whatever comes after image will be considered part of the command to start the container process.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by putting the image ID at the end of the command